# how to create multi items with 3 columns and be responsive

Tags: responsive-design, multiple-columns

I am wanting to create a layout that has 2 items side by side and each item has 3 columns.  The 1st and 2nd columns are fixed width and the 3rd column needs to fill the rest of the width and grow in height as needed for text.  These 2 side by side items would be a 50% split of items parent div.  Something like below.

```
-------------------------------------------   ------------------------------------------- 
| col1 | col2 | col 3 with copy that wraps |  | col1 | col2 | col 3 with copy that wraps |
|               when there is lots of text |  |               when there is lots of text |
|               in this column             |  |               in this column             |
-------------------------------------------   -------------------------------------------
```

or like this when parent div is smaller

```
 --------------------------------    -------------------------------- 
| col1 | col2 | col 3 with copy  |  | col1 | col2 | col 3 with copy  |
|               that wraps when  |  |               that wraps when  |
|               there is lots of |  |               there is lots of |
|               text in this     |  |               text in this     |
|               column           |  |               column           |
 --------------------------------    --------------------------------
```

This is close but I really do not want to use percentage on the width of the 3rd column for the text.

https://jsfiddle.net/fractorr/htzyLupz/4/

Answer (score 0):

If you use bootstrap, you can use the column division method to make the layout side by side

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- first item -->
    <div class="col-md-6">

        <div class="row">
            <!-- make column inside the outer column -->
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <!-- col1 -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <!-- col2 -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <!-- col 3 with wording -->
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- second item -->
    <div class="col-md-6">

        <div class="row">
            <!-- make column inside the outer column -->
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <!-- col 1 -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <!-- col 2 -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <!-- col 3 with wording -->
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Each row will consider as `col-md-12`. Plan on how you want to use the column size by adjusting the column size. 12 is max. Half is 6 and so on. Hope it help you.